Looking for a TV Show Based on a Children's Book
There were a series of children's books I read when I was a child. I think all schools in the UK used these books in the late 80's / early 90's for children to learn to read.
Fast forward several years and I stumbled along a late night BBC learning zone TV show based on these books.
The main protagonists were young boys (possibly three in total) of different ages and there was a dog (maybe white or grey in colour) and the adventures revolved around the dog wishing scenarios. I don't recall this happening in the books. I seem to remember a wooden box in the books. The show is a cartoon and not live action. The only episode I remember may have involved the boys being inside a computer game.
The TV show was on late nights (00:00-06:00am) BBC2 between 2003 and 2006, but probably 2004.
Whats the name of the TV show or books?

This is the BBC's adaptation of The Magic Key from the early 2000s.

The Magic Key is a series of books published for children as part of the Oxford Reading Tree, from Oxford University Press. The books are written by Roderick Hunt, illustrated by Alex Brychta, and primarily follow the lives of three children, Biff, Chip and Kipper Robinson.
In the television show, Floppy wears a collar around his neck with a golden key upon it. The key is magic, as the title suggests, and seems to do some strange things whenever Floppy wishes for something. It transports the children and sometimes their grandmother, to other worlds, where they have exciting adventures, such as dealing with trolls in an underground cavern, being characters inside a computer game, or finding the Fountain of Youth. In the books the key is kept in a box which opens the door to a dolls house and Floppy does not go on all the adventures.

Here's the episode where they're in a computer game:




YES!! That is it. So many childhood memories. Thanks!
